# Modals/dialogs, popovers, popups, alerts timing and easing

Tags: popup, dialog, alerts, popover

I am trying to find out evidence concerning how to handle both timing and ease of modals/dialogs, popovers, popups, alerts and so on.
Is there anyone who can share studies or links?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/animation-usability/  This is the article that you are looking for :)

Comment: The right answer is "it depends" which means you might want to be more specific. Articles won't provide much guidance with such an overarching context. Do you have a particular use-case that applies to something you're currently working on?

Comment: When you say evidence what do you mean? Seems your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an exact study which defines this kind of stuff. It all depends on the needs of the design system in place. For example, compare Material Design's modals 
( https://material.io/design/motion/understanding-motion.html# ) with the ones from Apple Design System ( https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/animation/ ). You will see that there is not a certain rule they follow.

However, you can find general (extremely general) guidelines, like: https://designmodo.com/design-modal-windows/ , from where you can get some tips of how to make a modal easier for the user to digest.

I hope that this helps you get closer to the answer you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful information at Material Deign's [**Dialogs**](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) section.

Comment: Hi Garik! I had already had a look both at Materials Design standards and the mani frontend frameworks such as Bootstrap, UIKit and Foundation.
I was wondering whether there was a source I could go through or not...